# Balancing the server load

Tags: strings, ruby, server

I've created a program that will take, a bunch of numbers from a `range` of 1 - 255, and then put them into 3 different strings(servers) equally. It does this by having a count that starts at 1 and loops to 3, once the count has hit 3 it restarts until three servers have hit a max capacity of 100 numbers within it.

Once that max capacity has been hit, the numbers dump the remaining into a server called `failsafe`.

I'm looking for better ways to write this, that are cleaner, and will make this, if possible, more readable.

```
#!/local/usr/bin/ruby

users = (1..255) #<= Amount of users

calculon = " " #<= Random servers to be append into
darth = " "
invader_zim = " "     
failsafe = " " #<= Failsafe

count = 1
users.each do |i|
  target_string = case count
   when 1 then calculon #<= Append into server
   when 2 then darth #<= Append into server
   when 3 then invader_zim #<= Append into server
  end

  target_string = failsafe if target_string.length == 100
  target_string << i #<= When amount is reached hits fail safe

  if count == 3
    count = 1
  else
    count += 1
  end
end


puts calculon.length == 1    ? 'No users on server' : calculon.length
puts darth.length == 1       ? 'No users on server' : darth.length
puts invader_zim.length == 1 ? 'No users on server' : invader_zim.length
puts failsafe.length == 1    ? 'No users on server' : failsafe.length
```

Example of usage:

> ```
> 86
> 86
> 86
> No users on server
> ```

The main objective of this program is to have a script that will equally load three different servers, and if all servers have hit a max capacity, will load into a fail safe server.

Comment: These are weird strings that you are composing. This feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you tell us more about what you _really_ want to do?

Comment: @200_success Yessir, give me 1 second

Comment: @200_success How's that..?

Comment: It still doesn't explain what you intend to do with those weird strings.

Comment: @200_success The empty ones?

Comment: Why do the strings start with a space? Why binary ASCII strings rather than an array of integers? Is the string length just a counting device, or will you be parsing out the results to identify which users got assigned there?

Comment: @200_success The string don't have to start with a space, it just made it look prettier, for now it's for counting.

Comment: @200_success I don't understand how you think this feels like an "XY Problem" the user is just asking for better ways to write the program, obviously it works.

Comment: Can't you just divide the number of users by 3? This feels a bit too hypothetical to me

Comment: @Caridorc How would dividing the users by three help me in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfect use case for `group_by`, which basically does all the work for you in a single line:

We also get the added benefit of having the user ids as arrays instead of strings.  This makes more sense, and if for some reason you do want to get the string representation back, you can simply call `join(' ')` on the array of user ids.

Finally, if you add more servers to your cluster, you just need to edit the single line defining the server names at the top of the file, and everything will still work.

```
users = (1..255) #<= Amount of users
servers = %w(calculon darth invader_zim)
server_capacity = 100

assigned_users = users.group_by.with_index do |u, i| 
  all_servers_full = (i >= servers.size * server_capacity)
  all_servers_full ? 'failsafe' : servers[i % servers.size]
end

assigned_users.each do |server, users|
  puts "#{server} server has #{users.size} users"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code-snippet you've 1x`case` and 2x`if/else` statements. It's better to use ruby iterators (like `with_index`, `with_object`). This way you're avoiding unnecessary variables and their "manual" incrementing (`count` in your case).
Also try to avoid unexplained "hard-coded" integers(`3`, `100`). Basically they're variables or constants.

Next weird strings... it's hard to understand their purpose. Why use `" "`, not empty string? Everywhere in code string length is used, not content.

Output lines can be easily organized with `each` and be more informative.

My variant of your code refactoring:

```
users = (1..255)

servers = Array.new(3, 0)
failsafe = 0
max_load = 100


users.each.with_index do |i, index|
  current = index%servers.count
  if servers[current] < max_load
  then servers[current] += 1
  else failsafe += 1
  end
end

server_list = servers + [failsafe]
%w(calculon darth invader_zim failsafe).each.with_index do |name, index|
  p "On '#{name}' server currently #{server_list[index] == 0 ? 'NO' : server_list[index]} users."
end
```